# Extracting lines from a bytearray

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, io

This class is part of a utility that reads lines from a set of nonblocking file descriptors, blocking only when there are no complete lines to emit.

```
class NonblockingLineBuffer:
    def __init__(self, fd, encoding):
        self.fd  = fd
        self.enc = encoding
        self.buf = bytearray()

    def absorb(self):
        while True:
            try:
                block = os.read(self.fd, 8192)
            except BlockingIOError:
                return

            if block:
                self.buf.extend(block)
            else:
                self.is_open = False
                # We don't close the file here because caller
                # needs to remove the fd from the poll set first.
                return

    def emit(self):
        def emit1(chunk):
            self.emitted_this_cycle = True
            return (self.fd, chunk.decode(self.enc).rstrip())

        buf = self.buf
        self.emitted_this_cycle = False
        while buf:
            r = buf.find(b'\r')
            n = buf.find(b'\n')
            if r == -1 and n == -1:
                if not self.is_open:
                    yield emit1(buf)
                    buf.clear()

            elif r == -1 or r > n:
                yield emit1(buf[:n])
                buf = buf[(n+1):]

            elif n == -1 or n > r:
                yield emit1(buf[:r])
                if n == r+1:
                    buf = buf[(r+2):]
                else:
                    buf = buf[(r+1):]

        self.buf = buf
        if not self.is_open:
            self.emitted_this_cycle = True
            yield (self.fd, None)
```

This question is specifically about `emit`, which is complicated, confusing, and might not be as efficient as it could be.  Please suggest ways to make it less complicated and/or confusing, and more efficient.

(I know it could be much simpler if it didn't need to reimplement universal newline handling, but that is unfortunately a requirement from the larger context.)

(If there's something in the standard library that does some or all of the larger task, that would also be a welcome answer.)

Comment: Would you post the entire utility that works with multiple file descriptors? I suspect that there's a simpler way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @200_success I made a bunch of changes since I posted the question, and I also got some good advice from Janne Karila about the narrowly-construed problem, so I've done as you suggest in a new question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84299/non-blocking-line-oriented-input-from-several-file-descriptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have overlooked a corner case: while you normally treat `\r\n` as a single separator, this not the case when the two bytes are split between blocks.
- [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.splitlines) could handle the universal newlines for you.

Here's what I came up with; still not very pretty I'm afraid. Initialize `self.carry_cr = False` in constructor.

```
def emit(self):
    buf = self.buf
    if buf:
        # skip \n if previous buffer ended with \r
        if self.carry_cr and buf.startswith(b'\n'):
            del buf[0]
        self.carry_cr = False

    lines = buf.splitlines()
    if buf:
        if self.is_open and not buf.endswith((b'\r', b'\n')):
            buf = lines.pop()
        else:
            if buf.endswith(b'\r'):
                self.carry_cr = True
            del buf[:]
    self.buf = buf

    self.emitted_this_cycle = False
    if lines:
        self.emitted_this_cycle = True
        for line in lines:
            yield (self.fd, line.decode(self.enc).rstrip())
    if not self.is_open:
        self.emitted_this_cycle = True
        yield (self.fd, None)
```

Comment: This is enough of an improvement over what I had that I'm going to accept this and ask a new question showing more of the context (as suggested by 200_success).  Thank you.