# Non-blocking line-oriented input from several file descriptors

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, io

This is a follow-up to [Extracting lines from a bytearray](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84234/extracting-lines-from-a-bytearray) ; I got a pretty good answer to the narrow question I asked there, but was invited to show more of the code in case there was a simpler way to solve the larger problem.  So here's my entire module.  Note that the use of `PollSelector` instead of `DefaultSelector` is intentional, as the expected use involves a bunch of threads each of which uses this to multiplex input from order of 3 file descriptors, so the overhead of kqueue/epoll/devpoll is undesirable and the linear cost of classic poll is not a problem.  Yes, it would arguably be better to merge all of those threads into one, but that would be a much larger overhaul than I can afford to make right now.

As before, I am primarily interested in improvements to efficiency, improvements to readability, and places where I'm not taking full advantage of the Python (3.4) standard library.  I am **not** interested in third-party modules even if they do substantially the same thing as this.

```
import fcntl
import heapq
import locale
import os
import selectors
import time

# This is a module global because locale.getpreferredencoding(True) is
# not safe to call off-main-thread.
DEFAULT_ENCODING = locale.getpreferredencoding(True)

class LineMultiplexor:
    """Priority queue which produces lines from one or more file objects,
       which are used only for their fileno() and as identifying
       labels, as data becomes available on each.  If data is
       available on more than one file at the same time, the user can
       specify the order in which to return them.  The user can also
       indicate that a particular file's lines should be processed in
       queue-sorted order, rather than as they come in.

       Files open in text mode are decoded according to their own
       stated encoding; files open in binary mode are decoded
       according to locale.getpreferredencoding().  Newline handling
       is universal.

       Files may be added or removed from the pollset with the
       add_file and drop_file methods (in the latter case, the file
       will not be closed).  You can pass in bare fds as well as file
       objects.  Files are automatically removed from the pollset and
       closed when they reach EOF.

       Each item produced by .get() or .peek() is (fileobj, string);
       trailing whitespace is stripped from the string.  EOF on a
       particular file is indicated as (fileobj, None), which occurs
       only once; when it occurs, fileobj has already been closed.

       If no data is available (either from .peek(), or after .get
       times out) the result is (None, None).

       If used as an iterator, iteration terminates when all files have
       reached EOF.  Adding more files will reactivate iteration.
    """

    def __init__(self, default_timeout=None):
        self.poller          = selectors.PollSelector()
        self.output_q        = []
        self.default_timeout = default_timeout
        self.seq             = 0

    def add_file(self, fp, priority=0, sort_lines=False):
        """Add FP to the poll set with priority PRIORITY (default 0).
           Larger priority numbers are _lower_ priorities.
           If SORT_LINES is true, the lines of this file will be
           produced in alphabetical order (within each chunk) rather
           than file order.
        """
        buf = NonblockingLineBuffer(
            fp,
            lineno   = -1 if sort_lines else 0,
            priority = priority
        )
        self.poller.register(fp, selectors.EVENT_READ, buf)

    def drop_file(self, fp):
        """Remove FP from the poll set.  Does not close the file."""
        self.poller.unregister(fd)

    def peek(self):
        """Returns the first item in the output queue, if any, without
           blocking and without removing it from the queue.
        """
        if not self.output_q:
            self._poll(0)
        return self._extract(False)

    def get(self, timeout=None):
        """Retrieve the first item from the output queue.  If there
           are none, blocks until data arrives or TIMEOUT expires."""
        self._poll(timeout)
        return self._extract(True)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Iteration calls .get until all files are exhausted."""
        if not self.output_q and not self.poller.get_map():
            raise StopIteration
        return self.get()

    # Internal: queue management.
    def _insert(self, priority, lineno, line, fp):
        # self.seq ensures that everything in the queue is strictly
        # ordered before we get to 'fp', which prevents heapq from
        # trying to sort file objects.
        heapq.heappush(self.output_q, (priority, lineno, line, self.seq, fp))
        self.seq += 1

    def _extract(self, pop):
        if not self.output_q:
            return (None, None)
        if pop:
            qitem = heapq.heappop(self.output_q)
        else:
            qitem = self.output_q[0]
        return (qitem[4], qitem[2])

    # Internal: the core read loop.
    def _poll(self, timeout=None):
        if timeout is None:
            timeout = self.default_timeout

        while True:
           if timeout is not None and timeout > 0:
               entry = time.monotonic()

            events = self.poller.select(timeout)
            if events:
                may_emit = []
                for k, _ in events:
                    buf = k.data
                    if buf.absorb():
                        may_emit.append(buf)

                for buf in may_emit:
                    lineno = buf.lineno
                    prio = buf.priority
                    for line in buf.emit():
                        self._insert(prio, lineno, line, buf.fp)
                        if lineno != -1:
                            lineno += 1

                    buf.lineno = lineno
                    if buf.at_eof:
                        self.drop_file(buf.fp)
                        buf.close()

            if self.output_q or timeout == 0:
                break

            # If some of the file descriptors are slowly producing very
            # long lines, we might not actually emit any data for longer
            # than the timeout, even though the system call never blocks
            # for too long.  Therefore, we must manually check whether
            # the timeout has expired, and adjust it downward if it hasn't.
            if timeout is not None and timeout > 0:
                now = time.monotonic()
                timeout -= now - entry
                if timeout <= 0:
                    break

class NonblockingLineBuffer:
    """Helper class used by LineMultiplexor; responsible for buffering
       input from individual file descriptors until full lines are
       available."""

    def __init__(self, fp, lineno, priority):
        global DEFAULT_ENCODING

        self.fp = fp
        self.lineno = lineno
        self.priority = priority

        if hasattr(fp, 'fileno'):
            self.fd = fp.fileno()
            if hasattr(fp, 'encoding'):
                self.enc = fp.encoding
            else:
                self.enc = DEFAULT_ENCODING
        else:
            assert isinstance(fp, int)
            self.fd  = fp
            self.enc = DEFAULT_ENCODING

        self.buf = bytearray()
        self.at_eof = False
        self.carry_cr = False

        fl = fcntl.fcntl(self.fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
        if not (fl & os.O_NONBLOCK):
            fcntl.fcntl(self.fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

    def close(self):
        if hasattr(self.fp, 'close'):
            self.fp.close()
        else:
            os.close(self.fd)

    def absorb(self):
        while True:
            try:
                block = os.read(self.fd, 8192)
            except BlockingIOError:
                break
            if not block:
                self.at_eof = True
                break

            self.buf.extend(block)

        return bool(buf) or self.at_eof

    def emit(self):
        buf = self.buf

        if buf:
            # Deal with '\r\n' having been split between absorb() events.
            if self.carry_cr and buf[0] == b'\n':
                del buf[0]
            self.carry_cr = False

        if buf:
            lines = buf.splitlines()
            if self.is_open and buf[-1] not in (b'\r', b'\n'):
                buf = lines.pop()
            else:
                if buf[-1] == b'\r':
                    self.carry_cr = True
                del buf[:]

            for line in lines:
                yield (self.fp, line.decode(self.enc).rstrip())

        if self.at_eof:
            yield (self.fp, None)

        self.buf = buf
```

Comment: I see references to `poller` which probably should be `self.poller`. Have you tested this version of the code at all?

Comment: @JanneKarila Unfortunately not; the larger application still has parts all over the floor.  I'll correct that here, though.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that would worry me if I had to use or maintain this code is that the interface is very complex. That big docstring for `LineMultiplexor` is a hint that this class is trying to do too many things, and I would want to try to refactor it into a set of simpler classes.

Normally one tries to follow the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), but the `LineMultiplexor` class has *five* main areas of responsibility:

1. Maintaining a set of file descriptors.
2. Multiplexing lines of input from these file descriptors.
3. Decoding the lines.
4. Sorting the lines according to the priority of the file descriptors and (optionally) the lines themselves.
5. Stripping trailing whitespace.

I can understand how a [big ball of mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/mud.html) like this develops: you start out with a class handling one area of responsibility, and then as you discover new requirements it is always easier to add functionality to an existing class than to redesign and refactor.

My initial refactoring plan would look like this:

1. Delegate the decoding of lines to `NonblockingLineBuffer`.
2. Leave out the stripping of trailing whitespace. (The caller can do it if they need.)
3. Split what's left into two classes, one to handle the multiplexing and one to handle the sorting.

Other points that I noticed:

1. "Multiplexer" is spelled thus.
2. There seems to be a typo in `drop_file` (`fd` should be `fp`). This suggests that you haven't actually run or tested this code, and so it's massively premature to ask people to review it.
3. The multiplexer turns on `O_NONBLOCK` for each file descriptor added to the set. This behaviour ought to be documented.
4. Returning exceptional values like `(None, None)` leads to error-prone code (the caller has to remember to check for the exceptional value and it's easy to forget). Better to raise an exception.
5. Similarly, returning `(fd, None)` to indicate end of file seems like it's going to be awkward to handle. Are you sure you need this? What would the caller be able to do about it anyway, since you've already closed the file. It might be better to have some other mechanism for signalling end of file.
6. The `NonblockingLineBuffer` class has `lineno` and `priority` attributes that it does not actually use. (They are only used by `LineMultiplexor`.) It's worth avoiding this kind of tight coupling between classes if possible.
7. Consider using `seq = itertools.count()` and then `next(seq)`.
8. Similarly, considering using `lineno = itertools.repeat(-1) if sort_lines else itertools.count()` and then `next(lineno)`.